# Getting Exclamation Mark Image in the place of FusionCharts

Tags: fusioncharts

I'm using FusionCharts in my webpage. i'm rendering the same portlet with fusioncharts twice in the page. Sometimes i'm getting a big Exclamation Mark (!) in a grey circle in the place of charts. 
And it happens only sometimes, so i'm not sure how to replicate this scenario or why this happens.

Has anyone faced similar issue?

Note: the div id for the fusioncharts is different in the page. So same div id is not whats causing this.

If anyone can give me any solution, it will be great.

Screenshot:

[image: Exclamation]

Unfortunately, i cannot share the code base in the forum. I'm sure there is nothing wrong in the code because the chart renders almost always. This happens very rarely but still is a problem.

Comment: Posting a screenshot and code that was used to generate the chart would be extremely useful.

Answer (score 0):

Without a code or sample that can reproduce this, my answer would be based on checking the best practices

1. Ensure you do not have duplicate chart id
2. Ensure you either re-render existing chart or update data - at least ensure to dispose unneeded charts if you are re-rendering
3. Ensure that the div where chart is being rendered is "visible" during the rendered process.
4. If you have many interactive activities with the charts - like tab change, etc... ensure you sync them with chart events such as `rendered`, `disposed`, etc (this will avoid issues with errors in partial rendering of charts)
5. Check your JS console for errors when this (!) things happen.
6. I am curious though ... something is rendering the (!) ... if you are rendering Flash based charts, it maybe due to Flash plugin crashing. Try forcing JS rendering of charts.